# Como bloquear botoes de menu, quando um formulário ainda não foi salvo, é possível?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sou novo por aqui. Estou iniciando em c# e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho um formulário, onde eu ainda não dei um `post` ainda, e eu não queria deixar que o usuário saísse dessa tela sem salvar.

Qual a melhor prática para se fazer isso?

Comment: Pablo, você não gostaria que usuário saísse da página sem submiter o formulário, porém não quer permitir que ele saísse para qualquer página? Tipo se ele clicar em outro link na página, se ele der um voltar no browser. Explique melhor o seu objetivo com o post e se possível poste o código que fez até agora.

Comment: Não tenho código ainda, pois estamos pois somente irei programar quando questões como está forem sanadas.
Estou apenas no planejamento
A idéia é isso mesmo, bloquear qualquer link, ou exibir uma tela informando que as informações não serão salvar caso não clique em salvar.
Qual seria a melhor saída, jqueri, javascript....

Answer (score 3):

A melhor alternativa é usando [jQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Coloque isso dentro das tags `<script>` e `</script>`:

[Aqui explica mais especificamente o *handler* `unload`](https://api.jquery.com/unload/).

Comment: Valeu, isso já dará uma direção para o desenvolvimento.